# php set user environment using cli on windows

Tags: php

I am trying to set a user environment variable, but couldn't find a solution to achieve this.
I am able to read a user environment variable with:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshEnv = $WshShell->Environment("USER");
$tempPath = $WshEnv->Item("TEMP");
```

But how can I set a variable if I would like to use COM at php?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [`putenv('VARIABLE=value')`](http://php.net/putenv) function.